# using props in other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby

Today I'm working with a React/Gatsby website. I would like to make a banner on each page. I would like to make a component and use a parameter. I use my photo as parameter.

But everytime I get the error: "**Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**"

Index.js:

```
<Banner image={<image parameter>} alt="..."/>
```

and on my Banner.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Banner = () => {
  return (
      <img src={ this.props.image } className={'banner-fullwidth'} alt={"Banner on page"}/>
  )
}

export default Banner;
```

What is wrong in my code?

---

Still got the problem:

Even if I change my function with props in the arrow function.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in a functional component, not in a class, so instead of using the `this` keyword, you access the `props` like such:

```
const Banner = (props) => {
  return (
      <img src={ props.image } className={'banner-fullwidth'} alt={"Banner on page"}/>
  )
}
```

You can read more about Components and Props [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).

Answer (score 0):

Your Banner is functional component so use `props.image` not `this.props.image` because `this.props.image` is for class based component.

```
const Banner = (props) => {
  return (
      <img src={ props.image } className={'banner-fullwidth'} alt={"Banner on page"}/>
  )
}
```

Define/pass your props like `const Banner = (props) => {}`

Or

**destructure** to avoid props.

```
const Banner = ({image }) => {
      return (
          <img src={image} className={'banner-fullwidth'} alt={"Banner on page"}/>
      )
    }
```

Comment: @user12380607 check this solution

Comment: Look at my answer!

Comment: @user12380607 resolved check 2nd solution of destructuring

Comment: why do I have to use image in the arrow function?

Comment: @user12380607 that's the concept of Es6 destructuring to write clean code. check this for better understanding https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Yea I know what you mean, but it's in an other page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't use 'this' in a functional component. So instead of this, use props. However I see that you didn't pass props as a parameter in the banner component.

So what you ought to do is

```
const Banner = (props) => {
 return (
  <img src={ props.image } />
 )
 }
```

Or the more elegant way by destructure/ pulling out image from the prop